# OpenVPN connect but nothing else

Tags: 13.04, vpn, openvpn

I have installed a VPN server on my Synology DS413+. I can connect but can't ping or do anything else. I think it has to do with the route but I don't know how to change it.

Here is my output of route:

without VPN:

```
Kernel-IP-Routentabelle
Ziel            Router          Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         alice.box       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
```

with VPN:

```
Kernel-IP-Routentabelle
Ziel            Router          Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.0.9     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 tun0
???.???.???.??? 192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlan0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 tun0
192.168.0.0     192.168.0.9     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.0.1     192.168.0.9     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
192.168.0.9     *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.1.0     192.168.0.9     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
```

The ???.???.???.??? is just my VPN server and just for security.

I use ubuntu 13.04 and a Lenovo x220i. I would be pleased if somebody could help.

Answer (score 1):

Well I had the same problem but what I did to remedy the situation was to change the configuration of the vpn to only use the VPN for the resources on the VPN and that will allow you to browse through the normal route and access you synology on the vpn, hope that helps!